# What happens to the depth buffer if I discard a fragment in a shader using early_fragment_tests?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm using a fragment shader which discards some fragments using the *discard* keyword. My shader also uses the *early_fragment_tests* ( image store load obliges ).

**EDIT** :
I do not write the `gl_FragDepth`, I let the standard OpenGL handle the depth value.

**Will my depth buffer be updated with the fragment's depth before the discard keyword is executed?**

**EDIT** :
It **does not** seems like it on my NVidia Quadro 600 and K5000.

**Any clue where I could find that information?** FYI, I searched http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt. I found close enough topics but not that particular one.

Comment: I ran some tests with a simpler program and it seems that it does not get updated after all... I'm still wondering if it's implementation-dependent or not.

Comment: I just found my answer, it is implementation-dependent. I ran some tests on a K3000M with the same driver version as my K5000 and it updates the Depth buffer even if I discard my fragment.

Answer (score 4):

> Will my depth buffer be updated with the fragment's depth before the discard keyword is executed?

No, this sort of behavior is explicitly forbidden in a shader that contains `discard` or that writes an arbitrary value to `gl_FragDepth`. This is because in such a shader, the depth of your fragment after it is shaded may be unrelated the position generated during initial rasterization (pre-shading).

Without writing to `gl_FragDepth` or discarding, the depth of a fragment is actually known long before the actual fragment shader executes and this forms the foundation for early depth tests. Rasterization/shading can be skipped for some (individual tiled regions) or all of a primitive if it can be determined that it would have failed a depth test ***before*** the fragment shader is evaluated, but if the fragment shader itself is what determines a fragment's depth, then all bets are off.

There is an exception to this rule in DX11 / OpenGL 4.x. If you write your shaders in such a way that you can guarantee the output depth will always preserve the result of a depth test (same result as the depth generated during rasterization), early fragment tests can be enabled in a shader that uses `discard` or writes to `gl_FragDepth`. This feature is known as **[conservative depth](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/conservative_depth.txt)**, and unless you use this it is generally understood that `discard` is going to break early depth optimizations across the board.

Now, since you should never write to the depth buffer before you know whether the value you are writing passes or fails a depth test (`gl_FragDepth` may be different) or if the fragment even survives (`discard` may be used), you can see why a primitive shaded by a fragment shader that contains `discard` cannot write to the depth buffer before the shader is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I was misunderstood : I don't explicitly write to gl_FragDepth (**nowhere** in any control path of the shader), I'm using the default depth buffer writing mechanism. That is, draw some stuff with a fragment shader that can discard fragments or not. The fragment shader enables early_fragment_tests. I wanted to make sure that my fragment would not update the depth buffer with the depth value ( computed before the fragment shader ).

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu: I never said you did write to `gl_FragDepth`. I was giving you the rationale for why depth writes cannot be performed before a shader is fully executed; there are two circumstances, `discard` and writing to `gl_FragDepth`. If your shader contains neither, then this optimization is possible but if it contains either one then depth writes only occur ***after*** the shader is fully executed. In any case, you are not using a standard depth writing mechanism if you shader contains `discard`, as I tried to point out, early fragment tests are undefined in this situation.

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu: That is of course, unless you use the conservative depth extension I pointed out. Then early fragment tests will function in a shader that modifies the depth ***after*** execution. Discarding a fragment is, by the way, a modification of the depth -- the depth generated during rasterization is not what is written after the shader is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the information you are looking for is on that page:

> If early fragment tests are enabled, any depth value computed by the
>   fragment shader has no effect.  Additionally, the depth buffer, stencil
>   buffer, and occlusion query sample counts may be updated even for
>   fragments or samples that would be discarded after fragment shader
>   execution due to per-fragment operations such as alpha-to-coverage or
>   alpha tests.

The word "may" in "the depth buffer, [etc.] may be updated", implies it is implementation dependent (or completely random).

Comment: Yeah I read that info but it seemed to me that it was about fragments that gets discarded **after** the fragment shader execution, not by the *discard* keyword. Correct me if I'm wrong. I've read somewhere else that it is because of the deprecated status of the alpha tests.

Comment: The wording of that paragraph is open to interpretation, but I think that "per-fragment operations such as alpha-to-coverage or alpha tests." could include using `discard` in the fragment shader. I must admit that I translated "alpha tests" in the quoted paragraph to using `discard` in my head because I'm doing a lot of OpenGL ES 2 work at the moment (where `discard` is the only way to do alpha test).

Comment: @GuyRT: You ought to translate it that way, to be honest. That is the only way to implement alpha tests in modern OpenGL. It is not like there is dedicated alpha test hardware on GPUs, its just added implementation baggage that happens after fragment shading in compatibility profiles. Since it can be done in a fragment shader it was removed from ES 2.0 and GL 3.0.

Comment: The "that would be discarded **after** fragment shader execution" part makes me believe that there is a *before* and a **during**. Hence NOT including the *discard* keyword. And as a matter of fact, after running some tests, seems to be the case actually. I will run more tests on different hardware and post the results.

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu: You are right, there is a before and during. When primitives are rasterized, they have a known depth before the fragment shader executes. You can also write an arbitrary depth to `gl_FragDepth` or `discard` the depth generated during rasterization in a fragment shader - if your shader does either of these two things then an OpenGL implementation is not allowed to write the depth value before executing the shader. In fact, `early_fragment_tests` does not actually work in a shader that does either of these two things (at least not the depth test portion... stencil ***may***).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Are you sure the situation is the same when the `early_fragment_tests` qualifier is used in a shader vs the early z optimization (which is disabled in the presence of `discard`)? It seems odd that implementations are given latitude to update-or-not the depth buffer when an alpha test fails, but not given the same latitude for `discard`ed fragments. It is a shame that the issue isn't addressed explicitly in the `shader_image_load_store` spec.

Comment: @GuyRT: I have different behaviors with 2 NVidia cards with same driver version.